# Is there a way of creating an IdentityMap in scala 2.8

Tags: scala, collections, scala-2.8

There used to be an `IdentityHashMap` in `collection.jcl`: is there a way of constructing the same thing in the new 2.8 collections library (perhaps with a bespoke equality-relation)?

Comment: By the way, could you explain what you mean by "a bespoke equality relation?"

Comment: I just meant a way of injecting *a equals b iff X holds* for some X which you can define yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `scala.collection.mutable.HashMap` there are two protected methods, `elemEquals` and `elemHashCode`. If you override them you can create an `IdentityHashMap` of your own.

In `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap` there is only `elemHashCode`. (I don't know why, offhand.)

Comment: This wouldn't work for immutable maps because a new one is created every time an addition is made. So you'd have to modify the updated/remove logic as well, which could quickly get messy